# variable 'x' in projection not present in GROUP BY

Tags: java, select, rdf, sparql, sesame

I want to count municipalities and what I have in parentheses work. However, I want to get another variable too, but when I am adding it to SELECT, I am getting:

> org.openrdf.query.MalformedQueryException: variable 'region_name' in projection not present in GROUP BY.

In my query I have:

```
"SELECT ?region_name (COUNT(?municipality) AS ?count) " +
```

What am I missing?

Notice that I do not have anything like GROUP anywhere in my project, I think it is happening internally of Sesame.

I just saw that if I remove (COUNT...), I am getting the names as expected.

Comment: Can you show the complete query, rather than just a fragment?

Comment: Yes sir @JeenBroekstra..! I got a scary answer that worked, so no need to after all. :)

Comment: If such a scary answer works, please upvote and accept.

Comment: `COUNT` is an aggregate query which should result in an implicit group over all counted elements. Maybe it's complaining about that group with a slightly misleading message

Comment: @zapl thanks, but the scary answer did the trick. There is a scary limit for accepting the answer too Mr. Scary. :) HOwever, I did not accept it because it was not as precise as the other answer, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SPARQL, *every* query that uses an aggregate function (such as `COUNT`, `SUM`, `SAMPLE`, etc.) *always* uses a grouping. Even if you do not explicitly specify a `GROUP BY` clause in your query, it uses the 'default grouping' (that is, a single group to which all solutions belong).

In a SPARQL query which uses aggregates, non-aggregated variables (such as `?region_name`) may not be projected in the `SELECT` clause, unless they are explicitly added to the grouping.

The fix is to add an explicit `GROUP BY` to your query:

```
SELECT ?region_name (COUNT(?municipality) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ... 
}
GROUP BY ?region_name
```