# How to use GroupBy and GroupConcat in SPARQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sparql, group-concat

I am having a trouble with SPARQL query to group items. I am using http://kaiko.getalp.org/sparql to write my query.

I used GROUP BY on a field. Since there were multiple items, my result came as multiple rows and I am trying to concatenate them.

Here is my original query.

```
SELECT distinct ?word ?poslexinfo ?posdbnary ?def ?syn ?ant
WHERE { 
 ?f dbnary:describes ?lf. 
 ?lf rdf:type ontolex:LexicalEntry .
 ?lf lime:language "de" . 
 ?lf ontolex:canonicalForm ?wo .
 ?wo ontolex:writtenRep ?word .
 OPTIONAL {?lf lexinfo:partOfSpeech ?poslexinfo} .
 OPTIONAL {?lf dbnary:partOfSpeech ?posdbnary} .
 ?lf ontolex:sense ?os .
 ?os rdf:type ontolex:LexicalSense .
 OPTIONAL {?os dbnary:antonym ?ant} .
 OPTIONAL {?os dbnary:synonym ?syn} .
 ?os skos:definition ?defl .
 ?defl rdf:value ?def
 } LIMIT 5
```

Result:

```
word    poslexinfo  posdbnary   def     syn     ant

"gay"   http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#adjective   "Adjektiv"   "sexuelle Neigungen zum eigenen Geschlecht zeigend" http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/homosexuell http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/hetero

"gay"   http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#adjective   "Adjektiv"   "sexuelle Neigungen zum eigenen Geschlecht zeigend" http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/homosexuell http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/bi
```

Both these rows differ only in antonym and my expected output is,

```
word    poslexinfo  posdbnary   def     syn     ant

"gay"   http://www.lexinfo.net/ontology/2.0/lexinfo#adjective   "Adjektiv"   "sexuelle Neigungen zum eigenen Geschlecht zeigend" http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/homosexuell http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/hetero|http://kaiko.getalp.org/dbnary/deu/bi
```

I tried the below query using GroupBy and GroupConcat, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Query:

```
SELECT distinct ?word ?poslexinfo ?posdbnary ?def ?syn (GROUP_CONCAT(?ant ; separator="|") AS ?ants)
WHERE { 
 ?f dbnary:describes ?lf. 
 ?lf rdf:type ontolex:LexicalEntry .
 ?lf lime:language "de" . 
 ?lf ontolex:canonicalForm ?wo .
 ?wo ontolex:writtenRep ?word .
 OPTIONAL {?lf lexinfo:partOfSpeech ?poslexinfo} .
 OPTIONAL {?lf dbnary:partOfSpeech ?posdbnary} .
 ?lf ontolex:sense ?os .
 ?os rdf:type ontolex:LexicalSense .
 OPTIONAL {?os dbnary:antonym ?ant} .
 OPTIONAL {?os dbnary:synonym ?syn} .
 ?os skos:definition ?defl .
 ?defl rdf:value ?def
 } GROUP BY ?word LIMIT 5
```

When I try the above query, I get this error.

> Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: Variable ?syn is used in
>   the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable 'x' in projection not present in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033021/variable-x-in-projection-not-present-in-group-by)

Comment: You're just grouping by `word` - now go back to your example, the triple store built a group per each word, but now how can the triple store know what it has to do with all the other features. You did it for the `ant` column, but in general for each column there can be multiple values - thus you have to do something similar for those too. e.g. use `group_concat`. Clearly this would be wrong, you should also group by lexical sense or something to distinguish between different semantic meanings of the same word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Jeen Broekstra! The suggestion here helped in solving the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033146/73137.

```
SELECT ?word ?poslexinfo ?def (GROUP_CONCAT(?syn ; separator="||") AS ?syns) (GROUP_CONCAT(?ant ; separator="||") AS ?ants)
                WHERE {
                    ?f dbnary:describes ?lf.
                    ?lf rdf:type ontolex:LexicalEntry .
                    ?lf lime:language "de" .
                    ?lf ontolex:canonicalForm ?wo .
                    ?wo ontolex:writtenRep ?word .
                    OPTIONAL {?lf lexinfo:partOfSpeech ?poslexinfo} .
                    OPTIONAL {?lf dbnary:partOfSpeech ?posdbnary} .
                    ?lf ontolex:sense ?os .
                    ?os rdf:type ontolex:LexicalSense .
                    OPTIONAL {?os dbnary:antonym ?ant} .
                    OPTIONAL {?os dbnary:synonym ?syn} .
                    ?os skos:definition ?defl .
                    ?defl rdf:value ?def
                } GROUP BY ?word ?syn ?def ?posdbnary ?poslexinfo LIMIT 20
```