# Aggregate inside Subquery for SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, opendata

Im a using Virtuoso and DBpedia as an endpoint.

My purpose is to retrieve all movies which have a greater amount of actor than the mean number of actors for all movies.

I thought the following query would work:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT 
      DISTINCT ?film
      COUNT(?actor) AS ?numActors
WHERE{
    ?film rdf:type dbp:Film .
    ?film dbp:starring ?actor .
    {
        SELECT 
            AVG(?numActors) AS ?avgNumActors
        WHERE{
              SELECT  
                      ?Sfilm 
                      COUNT(?Sactor) AS ?numActors 
              WHERE{
                      ?Sfilm rdf:type dbp:Film .  
                      ?Sfilm dbp:starring ?Sactor
                    }
             }

    }

}
GROUP BY ?film 
HAVING (COUNT(?actor) > ?avgNumActors)
LIMIT 20
```

but I receveice the following error

> Variable ?avgNumActors is used in the result set outside aggregate and not mentioned in GROUP BY clause

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [variable 'x' in projection not present in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34033021/variable-x-in-projection-not-present-in-group-by)

Comment: yeah, to be fair - SPARQL isn't very intuitive in this case. I mean, it's clearly just a single value that the subquery returns, so doing `group by ?avgNumActors` is no t what a user would expect to do. On the other hand, SPARQL does not know that it is a single value, it's basically a resultset of size 1

Comment: also, no need for `DISTINCT` when doing group by

Comment: maybe a more intuitive (it splits the work into two tasks and then uses a "good old" filter): `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT 
?film
?numActors
{

{
SELECT 
?film
(COUNT(?actor) AS ?numActors)
WHERE{
    ?film a dbo:Film .
    ?film dbo:starring ?actor .
}
GROUP BY ?film
}
{
        SELECT 
            (AVG(?numActors) AS ?avgNumActors)
        WHERE{
              SELECT  
?Sfilm 
(COUNT(?Sactor) AS ?numActors) 
WHERE{
?Sfilm a dbo:Film .  
?Sfilm dbo:starring ?Sactor
 }
 }

}
filter(?numActors > ?avgNumActors)
}
LIMIT 20`

Comment: Thank you very much @UninformedUser, I see you are a man of winsdom. Do you work on the field of Open Linked Data?